# Filter Business Catalyst Web App Items by Category WITHIN Web App Item Detail Layout

Tags: liquid, business-catalyst

I am trying to list web app items filtered by Category classification within the detail layout of another web app.

To explain further, I have **Web App 1** (Learning Areas) which contains items like Science, English, Maths, etc. Each item is classified using BC's: Science, English, Maths, etc.

I also have **Web App 2** (Resources) which will contain a wide range of teaching material. Each item will also be classified using BC's Categories.

**I want to display items from Web App 2 inside the details layout of Web App 1 according to the Category classification of the "current" Web App 1 item.**

BC by default allows you to output a list of web app items according to a Category ID, eg

`{module_webapps id="Web App 2 ID" filter="classified" itemId="Category ID"}`

This won't work because I'm going to be placing this inside the detail layout of Web App 1 so the Category ID needs to change depending on what Web App 1 item we are on.

For instance, on the Science page (Web App 1 item classified as Science), Web App 2 items that have been classified as Science will be displayed, on the English page (Web App 1 item classified as English), Web App 2 items that have been classified as English will be display, and so on for each of the different learning areas.

Is there a way to do this? I had hoped there might be a `{tag_categoryId}` available so that I could do something like:

`{module_webapps id="Web App 2 ID" filter="classified" itemId="{tag_categoryId}"}`

but there is only `{tag_classifications}` which outputs the Category name, NOT the ID which is what is required.

Is there some way to do this with Liquid perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is possible using BC's Liquid markup.

It's a bit of a workaround but it isn't difficult and it works.

My solution requires:

- the `{{classifications}}` tag (legacy syntax is `{tag_classifications}`), available inside web app detail layout
- `{module_categorylist}` (when surrounded by `<select>` tags, this by default outputs a dropdown list of every Category on the website)

You can suppress the default rendering of `{module_categorylist}` by using `template=""` and can assign the data to a collection which can be accessed with Liquid:

```
{module_categorylist collection="gttCategories" render="collection" template=""}
```

**So my solution is as follows:**
(The following code is inserted into the Web App 1 detail layout.)

```
{module_categorylist collection="myCategories" render="collection" template=""}

{% for item in myCategories.items -%}

    {% if item.name == {{this.classifications}} -%}

        {module_webapps id="Web App 2 ID" filter="classified" itemId="{{item.id}}"}

    {% endif -%}

{% endfor -%}
```

The FOR statement iterates through the list of Categories outputted in the collection *myCategories* from the `{module_categorylist}`.

The IF statement looks at the name of each Category item within the list and compares it to `{{classifications}}`. (`{{classifications}}` outputs the Category name of the "current" Web App 1 item.)

For each match, it renders the Web App 2 module with the ID of that Category inserted into the itemId parameter.